# possible to render canvas drawing into div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a shape on an HTML5 canvas but have the shape appear in a div (that can be manipulated by javascript). How can i do this? I would post code but i dont even know where to start with this. Please help.

To clarify: i want the shapes rendered on the canvas to be placed in divs. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Put the canvas in a div? What do you want?

Comment: You can manipulate a `<canvas>`-element with JavaScript as you do with `<div>`-elements (except the content).

Comment: @pimvdb--i want the shapes rendered on the canvas to be placed in divs. Sorry, shhould have made that more clear.

Comment: @Jonas--ah.. manipulating the content of the canvas is exactly what i want to do. I suppose i'll have to make multiple canvases and place each one inside a div?

Comment: You suppose have to make multiple canvases and place each one inside a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla Drawing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

```
<div>
  <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
   var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
   // Set width height.  You should probably use the width/height of the div.
   canvas.width = 300;
   canvas.height = 300;
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   //  Draw something with ctx.....
   //  ....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/). It will allow you to convert what's on the Canvas into an image.  There are some quirks on a per browser basis, but it is the closest thing to what you want to do without having to put many canvas elements on your page that you update in tandem.